# How to fix problem in visualizing the algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, async-await, backtracking

I wanted to implement a question where we find paths in a maze from (0,0) cell to (m-1,n-1) cell with having some obstacles in between.
I have used recursive backtracking algorithm to solve the problem and I just wanted to make some kind of visualization where we can see how the path is been taken as we are travelling in the maze.
I saw that question [here](https://www.pepcoding.com/resources/online-java-foundation/recursion-backtracking/flood-fill-official/ojquestion)

Now I have implemented it using javascript and I am coloring the cells blue which we are visiting and then again removing the color if we backtrack but everything happens very fast as we can't see anything happening, so I tried using `sleep()` function to have some delay but I don't think I have used them properly as any random pattern is showing not the proper path it is taking.

If anyone could help me in resolving it then it will be a great help.
You can check my problem [here](https://codepen.io/sachuverma/pen/MWyBxvm)

My algorithm for finding path is :

```
let getMazePath = async (maze, r, c, ans) => {
  if (
    r < 0 ||
    c < 0 ||
    r >= maze.length ||
    c >= maze[0].length ||
    maze[r][c] == 1 ||
    visited[r][c] == 1
  )
    return;

  if (r == maze.length - 1 && c == maze[0].length - 1) {
    document.getElementById("path-display").innerHTML =
      "Path is: '" + ans + "'";
    console.log("Path is: '" + ans + "'");
    return;
  }

  let currSq = document.getElementById(r + "_" + c);
  currSq.classList.add("visited-square");
  await sleep(1000);
  visited[r][c] = 1;

  getMazePath(maze, r - 1, c, ans + "t");
  getMazePath(maze, r, c - 1, ans + "l");
  getMazePath(maze, r + 1, c, ans + "d");
  getMazePath(maze, r, c + 1, ans + "r");

  visited[r][c] = 0;
  currSq.classList.remove("visited-square");
  await sleep(1000);
};

function sleep(ms){
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've forgotten to await the recursive calls.

Fix it by prefixing `getMazePath` calls by `await`:

```
await getMazePath(maze, r - 1, c, ans + "t");
await getMazePath(maze, r, c - 1, ans + "l");
await getMazePath(maze, r + 1, c, ans + "d");
await getMazePath(maze, r, c + 1, ans + "r");
```

See it live [on CodePen](https://codepen.io/FZs111/pen/vYGaMXN)

---

You might also want to stop it, when it finds a path.

To do that, return the answer, and check for it:

```
let getMazePath = async (maze, r, c, ans) => {
  if (
    r < 0 ||
    c < 0 ||
    r >= maze.length ||
    c >= maze[0].length ||
    maze[r][c] == 1 ||
    visited[r][c] == 1
  )
    return; 

  if (r == maze.length - 1 && c == maze[0].length - 1) {
    document.getElementById("path-display").innerHTML =
      "Path is: '" + ans + "'";
    console.log("Path is: '" + ans + "'");
    return ans;
        // ^^^
  }

  let currSq = document.getElementById(r + "_" + c);
  currSq.classList.add("visited-square");
  await sleep(1000);
  visited[r][c] = 1;

  {
    const res = await getMazePath(maze, r - 1, c, ans + "t");
    if(res) return res
  }
  {
    const res = await getMazePath(maze, r, c - 1, ans + "l");
    if(res) return res
  }
  {
    const res = await getMazePath(maze, r + 1, c, ans + "d");
    if(res) return res
  }
  {
    const res = await getMazePath(maze, r, c + 1, ans + "r");
    if(res) return res
  }
  visited[r][c] = 0;
  currSq.classList.remove("visited-square");
  await sleep(1000);
};
```

See it live [on CodePen](https://codepen.io/FZs111/pen/mdPjgLR)

Comment: could you tell me why adding await before recursive calls fixed it? I don't know much about async await.

Comment: @sachuverma Because it is a call made to an **async** function. Async functions return *immediately* after called, and returns a so-called Promise object, using which you can check the status of the call, but the execution of the async function happens asynchronously (hence the name, right?). `await` suspends the execution of an async function until a given Promise finishes. Without those `await`s, the function only *initiates* the recursive calls, but *doesn't wait for them to finish*. And multiple, concurrently executing functions that mutate the same objects can cause a **BIG** mess.